# How can I get my speaker to work?

Tags: power, mains, sound

I have a portable speaker and it recently stopped working. I don't need to but I am interested in trying to get it to work again, although I know very little about electronics!

I took the speaker apart and took out the 18650 battery after testing this with my multimeter it was obvious to me that the battery was dead. There was a small circuit connected to the battery which then had wires which plugged into the main PCB of the speaker. I guess this small circuit was an overcharge/overdischarge protection regulator thingy, as I think these batteries break if they are fully empty.

Without the battery in place the speaker turns on when plugged into the mains but as soon as I start playing music, it cuts and switches itself off.

I have a few questions about this.

1. Why doesn't the speaker work straight from the mains without the battery in place? (When the speaker was working it worked strsight from the mains)
2. Does the battery basically convert the AC to DC and thats why the speaker doesn't work without it?
3. How can I get the speaker to work without a battery (from the mains)?
4. How can I test the overcharge/discharge protector circuit to check it works, without potentially breaking another battery?

Comment: Try putting a large electrolytic capacitor inplace of where you battery went. Maybe 1000 uF at an appropriate voltage rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The probable reason for this is that the charging circuit can provide enough current to turn on the radio, but once you start playing music, the circuit cannot provide enough current to drive the speakers properly. This causes the voltage to sag, the circuit decides that something is wrong, and it cuts out. (Or it simply resets due to the voltage being lower than the operating voltage.)
2. No, the power supply / charging circuit converts the AC to DC. The battery simply acts as a reservoir.
3. Try following Andy aka's advice: "Try putting a large electrolytic capacitor inplace of where you battery went. Maybe 1000 uF at an appropriate voltage rating."
4. After connecting the capacitor, measure its voltage while you're charging the capacitor. I think it's reasonably safe to assume that the 18650 cell is a Li-ion with a nominal voltage of 3.7 V, so if the capacitor stops being charged at 4.2 V, that is good. Then disconnect the charging cable, and keep the player on until it shuts itself off due to low "battery". If the voltage on the capacitor is still more than 2.5 V (better still, over 3.0 V), that is also good. Take care not to electrocute yourself in the process.